# Subset the data in train and test in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to subset the data in train and test. the train data will contain values from particular columns with their rows.  Basically, I want to split CSAT columns all values with 0 in test and other values in train

| Contracted MRR | Region | CSAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 932.24 | NA | 0 |
| 390.83 | EMEA/ROW | 5 |
| 485.16 | NA | 1 |
| 845.21 | NA | 4 |
| 0 | EMEA/ROW | 0 |
| 0 | EMEA/ROW | 0 |
| 0 | APAC | 0 |
| 0 | APAC | 5 |
| 1764.15 | NA | 0 |
| 4165.82 | NA | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

filtering out rows based on 0 and non 0 values of CSAT column

```
test_df = data.loc[data.CSAT==0]
train_df = data.loc[data.CSAT!=0]
```

Comment: thank you. Can we do this train and test split function @Resham